# PHP, dynamic paging not working

Tags: php

I use this code, but it's not working correctly. It just output the `about.php` page. Why is this?

```
$halaman= isset($_GET['menu'] );
 switch ($halaman) :


    default:
        include "home.php";
        break;

    case 'about':
        include "about.php";
        break;
    case 'galery':
        include "galery.php";
        break; 
    endswitch;
```

Comment: you're going to have to define *"not working"*. There isn't enough code here neither. Are you not checking for errors also?

Comment: You need to switch based on `true` or `false` cuz that's what `isset` returns

Comment: isset returns a boolean, so $halmana is set to true/false when you presumably want the value stored in $_GET['menu'] for your switch statement.

Comment: And put the `default` at the end for heaven's sake  :)

Comment: i didnt found any error, but, my page should jump to galery.php but it not jump, just stay in about.php..

Comment: `$halaman= (isset($_GET['menu'] )) ? $_GET['menu']  : "";`

Comment: if l use $halaman= (isset($_GET['menu'] )) ? $_GET['menu'] will become error
unexpected 'switch' (T_SWITCH) in

Comment: @jaro21  check the answer below , i have added two working demo example for you. check and use any-one of them.Also if the answer worked for you then don't forget to mark the answer as accepted.Thanks

Answer (score 3):

`isset()` return a Boolean value so what you need to actually check and then assign `GET` value to your variable like below:-

```
$halaman= (isset($_GET['menu'] )) ? $_GET['menu'] : ""; // instead of "" you can add any other default value.  
 switch ($halaman) :

    default:
        include "home.php";
        break;

    case 'about':
        include "about.php";
        break;

    case 'galery':
        include "galery.php";
        break; 
    endswitch;
```

Demo example:-https://eval.in/837023

***Note:-***

You can apply ***`!empty()`*** instead of ***`isset()`*** also (it will check both that variable is set and have some value) and then you can do like below:-

Output:- https://eval.in/837028

Answer (score 2):

This should work since isset() returns a boolean value not a string.

```
    if(isset($_GET['menu'] )){
     switch ($_GET['menu']) :


        default:
            include "home.php";
            break;

        case 'about':
            include "about.php";
            break;
        case 'galery':
            include "galery.php";
            break; 
        endswitch;
}
```

Comment: `islet()` returns a small island.

Comment: Do or do not, there is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Thanks I'll edit

Answer (score 1):

`isset()` returns a boolean. Therefore the variable you are testing in your `switch` statement is just true or false.